# Can I use Mysqli inside of a Mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can someone please tell me if I need to upgrade my server to use mysqli?  I unfortunately for now see the need to use mysqli for numerous reasons but my hosting company only offers mysql database...
Can I use mysqli statements in mysql database?

Comment: Yes you can, you could probably even use PDO (safer)

Comment: Is there a huge syntax difference?

Comment: Between PDO and MySQL yes, for safety purposes it is structured to accept variables in a different manner. Between MySQLi and MySQL some, not much.

Comment: What should I do.. do you recommend PDO instead of mysqli then? I am building my own ecommerce site and I was learning mysql..then I got discouraged because everyone says it's not secure anymore so now I have to start from scratch.. what do you think I should do?

Comment: Yes, build using PDO. For commerce use SSL as well.

Comment: I was afraid you'd day that.. so you think with a mysql database PDO will work then?

Comment: I don't want to waste my time learning something I won't be able to use with the resources I have

Comment: PDO works with a about twelve different types of databases, I'm confident it will work for you. But, again, in addition to safer PDO, I highly recommend SSL.

Comment: PDO that is then.. and that about ssl.. u mean security socket layer? I'm sorry if I sound stupid.. I'm trying to follow you

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO for safer variable management and data transfer, if built properly it helps prevent sql injection. PDO on its own does not offer any data security or privacy, which in your case of ecommerce, is of utmost importance these days. To assist with that, you will need SSL (Secure Socket Layer) certificate, your web host can help install it, and for some maybe even offer a free one.

Comment: Yeah I meant socket.. well.. for that I need prob comodo or verasign.. one last question Alex.. do I need to know mysql or mysqli a 100% or can I just jump to PDO and learn it from scratch? Like I said I was getting into mysql but I guess I'm done with that now

Comment: They are different enough that you can start PDO from scratch (i.m.o). Read the php PDO manual, Google it, and it can guide you easily. Plus, SO has tons of questions and answered related to it, for just about every issue.

Comment: Well.. you just answered everything I needed.. thanks a lot alex.. have a good evening

Answer (score 0):

Andy, MySQL is the database client and server itself. MySQL API along with MySQLi and PDO API are part of the PHP language. It may not be completely clear when learning new things where something begins and something else with a similar name separates from that. the MySQL API within PHP is deprecated and thus will eventually be removed entirely so you don't want to code with that. Your host should thus already have MySQLi turned on within PHP, but the better solution of PDO API makes the most sense.

Comment: Niagaradad... do I need to know mysql or mysqli at a 100 percent to learn PDO or I can just jump and learn it from scratch?

Comment: I need to learn this.. whatever is the best.. I got no choice

Comment: MySQL is the database. Alternately you could be using mssql or postgres or oracle as the database. PHP is one language you can use (asp or java could also be used among others) to connect and query with the database. If you are familiar with neither, check the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html)mysql manual specifically the tutorial in chapter 3. the [link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)PDO library is part of PHP and you can read about it in that manual.

Comment: it def does not seem that hard tho. I was able to connect pretty easy.. I still don't know the rest yet... I am talking about PDO